# HttpURLConnection show progress

Tags: java, android, http

I use HttpURLConnection to connect my Server.I want to show update proress.

```
URL url = new URL(RequestURL);
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.set...// many params.
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
dos.write("http String"); // eg Content-Disposition: form-data......
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file); // Take file to Stream.
while(){
   dos.write(fileString);// Take file Strean to memory.This place can take prograss,but just in momory,not post to server proress.
}
dos.flush();
InputStream input = conn.getInputStream(); // This place will post data to server,but i donot how to get progress.
```

Please help me ,thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for that.

Answer (score 0):

[AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) is deprecated, since API 30.

I manage to get progress from HttpURLConnection using **getContentLength()** and reading fixed chunks from the Stream. If the server doesn't include **Content-Length** header you'll have to find another way to get the total data size to be downloaded.

The snippet below shows a example of reporting download progress:

```
try {
        URL url = new URL(theURL);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "identity");
        
        InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        long totalLength = conn.getContentLengthLong();
        int resultLength;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[512];
        while ((resultLength = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            baos.write(buffer, 0, resultLength);

            if (totalLength > 0)
                // Report the progress using baos.size() and totalLength
        }
    } catch (Exception ex){
        // Deal with that
    }
```

You can replace **ByteArrayOutputStream** with **OutputStreamWriter** with the data is not binary.